# How does consecutive days work

Tags: support

I've visited the site every day for the past couple of months, every morning like clockwork.  But today when I visited, my consecutive day count had been reset.  How does the consecutive day counter work?  Are there any known issues with it?

Comment: Good question, not sure.  Were you not logged in yesterday so it didn't know who you were maybe?  I've never gotten any of those badges either which I find somewhat suspicious...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

StackExchange days change at 00:00:00 GMT every day.

Looking at your history I see no access on October 21st.  Looks like you had a string of consecutive days dating from August 24st up until October 20th.

Check what time zone you are in to see when the StackExchange day is for you.

There is some more information on [meta.stackoverflow.com](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions/67399#67399) under the Enthusiast and Fanatic badges.

Comment: Strange. Thanks for the answer; I know I was on yesterday, several times on several sites and voting. Not a big deal; I just found it curious. Thanks again!

Comment: Additionally, it's thought that viewing the main page doesn't always count as a visit. I always visit at least one question and then view my user profile in the top bar, and it always counts toward consecutive days.

Comment: @JonathanDrain - That was what I was wondering.  I have the page pinned in chrome, which is how I know I always visit, but I was busy at work, and didn't actually get a chance to peruse any questions, though I did view my profile.  Thanks!